# preview uploaded photo for dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Image is as a button to select a photo. once image is selected, selected image is viewed and generated new image button. I can to this for 1 parameter only using ID. how can I do it for multiple files?

```
document.getElementById('imgInp').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('fileinpt').click();
};

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imgInp').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('.imgpc').after('<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 imgpc"><div class="imagepreview"><span></span><img id="imgInp" src="images/add-photo.png" alt="Add more photo" /><input type="file" id="fileinpt" class="hidden"></div></div>');
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#fileinpt").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jshp6zst/1/)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061461/how-can-i-display-multiple-image/44061602

Comment: is this question part of some quiz ?

Comment: I dont think so. pls check my demo. @karthick

Comment: use css class selector to collect all inputs and you can iterate over them. Eg. $('.imgpc input[type="hidden"]).attr('id')

Answer (score 1):

try with this updated jquery

```
$(document).off('click', '#imgInp').on('click', '#imgInp', function (e) {
        $('#fileinpt').click();
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imgInp').attr('src', e.target.result);                
            $('#imgInp').attr("id", "newimgInp");            

            $('.imgpc').append('<div class="imagepreview"><span></span><img id="imgInp" src="images/add-photo.png" alt="Add more photo" /></div>');
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#fileinpt").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

jsfiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/jshp6zst/3/