# Join images and create map with each image with link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I want an idea or direction to join multiple images on the web page either using JavaScript or any scripting language that help me to join fit my images in the main sketch and I can have pragmatically access over these joined images like I can add  tag to it any other changes that I want to do it programmatically.
Thanks in advance

Comment: your query is not clear. provide more details

Comment: i have main map of my area where i need to add plots images inside that map and join them as single image these maps images that were shown as per the data saved in my database

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061461/how-can-i-display-multiple-image) your question ?